# SenchaTouch Picker implementation?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, picker

i'm using SenchaTouch and would like to use their Picker for a UI component.  I have this code:

```
        var datePicker = new Ext.Picker({
        slots: [
            {
            name : 'limit_speed',
            useTitles: true,
            title: 'Terminals',
                data : [
                    {text: 'Terminalq 1', value: 1},
                    {text: 'Terminal 2', value: 2},
                    {text: 'Terminal 3', value: 3},
                    {text: 'Terminal 4', value: 4}
                ]    
            }    
        ]

    });
```

Does anyone know how to get an event handler to work on the doneButton??

Comment: That is not syntactically valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a function to the change event.

```
datePicker.on('change', function(){
  // do some stuff
});
```

or

```
var datePicker = new Ext.Picker({
        slots: [
            {
            name : 'limit_speed',
            useTitles: true,
            title: 'Terminals',
                data : [
                    {text: 'Terminalq 1', value: 1},
                    {text: 'Terminal 2', value: 2},
                    {text: 'Terminal 3', value: 3},
                    {text: 'Terminal 4', value: 4}
                ]    
            }    
        ],   
        listeners: {
            change: {
                element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                fn: function(){ console.log('click el'); }
            }
        }
});
```

you could also add it to the 'hide' event, depends if you care about the value or not.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to take value of selected field u can use this code.

```
listeners: {
    change: function(picker,button) {
        selectedValue = picker.getValue()['limit_speed'];
        console.log(selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can get the selected value of dynamically created datepicker

listeners: {
                                    change: function(picker,selectedValue) {
                                        console.log(selectedValue);
                                    }
                                }